# Notice: Trying to get property 'num_rows' of non-object in

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php

$queryuser  = "SELECT id, email, firstname, lastname, address, city, country  FROM users WHERE role = 'client'";
$resultuser = $connection->query($queryuser);
if ($resultuser->num_rows > 0)
{
  // output data of each row
  while ($rowuser = $resultuser->fetch_assoc())
  {
    $id_user   = $rowuser['id'];
    $firstname = $rowuser['firstname'];
    $lasttname = $rowuser['lastname'];
    $email     = $rowuser['email'];
    $phone     = $rowuser['phone'];
    $city      = $rowuser['city'];
    $state     = $rowuser['state'];
    $address   = $rowuser['address'];
?>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Your query failed. Check for [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to find out why.

Comment: There's a really big, common, canonical duplicate for this ... if only SO's search was a little better I'd find it in a couple of seconds...

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and improve your question using the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54240336/edit) link below the question.

Comment: where you got `$connection`?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you've copied code from this page https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

- Please understand code line by line first. You have not define `$connection` variable in your code (may be it is a intentional approach for security).
- Your notice saying that you are trying to get `num_rows` property from the object `$resultuser` but in this query `$resultuser` is not a object due to any error/faults of your query because query() returns FALSE on failure and object on success.
- To confirm, you can check your result set by using var_dump();
- Please replace this line if **$resultuser->num_rows** > 0 with 
   (!empty($resultuser->num_rows) && ($resultuser->num_rows > 0)))